# How can I use graphical resources (stored in res\drawable folders) from NDK?

Tags: opengl, png, fopen, drawable

I need to use openGL in NDK, and I need to load and use some images (PNG), and maybe other files. These files are stored in res\drawable, res\drawable-hdpi, but I cannot access them with fopen()...
There is a way to do this?
Can somebody give me a piece of code for my problem, because it is quite urgent.

Thank you very much, and Merry Christmas,
Tibi.

Answer (score 0):

Try using perror (or strerror) to determine why fopen is failing.